# Cannot delete products from store

Tags: magento2, catalog, exception, delete

We are noticing that in our Magento 2 store we are unable to delete products, individually or in bulk, from the catalog page. When selecting a product and hitting Delete, we get an error that says the product couldn't be removed. An exception log is created in the report folder with the following text:

```
{
    "0": "The \"TEST BOW-Carbon-White\" product couldn't be removed.",
    "1": "<pre>#1 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]
        #2 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php:231]
        #3 Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]
        #4 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]
        #5 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:143]
        #6 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor#0000000029647274000000003e6a0177#, &Closure#0000000029647241000000003e6a0177#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]
        #7 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]
        #8 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/MassDelete\/Interceptor.php:26]
        #9 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]
        #10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#, &Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\MassDelete\\Interceptor#0000000029647274000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:99]
        #11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]
        #12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]
        #13 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]
        #14 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]
        #15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000296476f3000000003e6a0177#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]
        #16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]
        #17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000002964760f000000003e6a0177#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>",
    "url": "\/magento\/admin_s48a1\/catalog\/product\/massDelete\/key\/59cf992ab24157037c893c4a8e09ffc7570a78a1e070ee922b78a3f2bed5ce0e\/",
    "script_name": "\/magento\/index.php"
}\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000002964760f000000003e6a0177#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>",
    "url": "\/magento\/admin_s48a1\/catalog\/product\/massDelete\/key\/59cf992ab24157037c893c4a8e09ffc7570a78a1e070ee922b78a3f2bed5ce0e\/",
    "script_name": "\/magento\/index.php"
}
```

However, after pouring across this error message I am at a bit of a loss. Has anyone seen this before or similar or have any suggestions as to where I would start troubleshooting?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks muchly.

Comment: Can you please give more detail as to what products you have in your catalog? I might expect this if you have products that are related to each other - but less so if all simple products.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for your edits and question. The product in question is a simple product with no related products. However, we seem to have this issue with multiple types - it happens with simple products, configurable products, virtual products, etc.

Comment: can you share URL?

Comment: I would add debug/log `MassDelete->execute()` in `class MassDelete` and `public function delete(ProductInterface $product)` in `class ProductRepository` to get the full detail of the exception (`$e->getMessage()`) and also to confirm which of the three lines in the `try catch` block is the one throwing the exception and why.